# URL parsing issue : excluding '+' symbol

Tags: javascript, node.js, urlparse

I have a URL

```
viberpa://aafff+a@viber.com?phone_number=vv+9nc3pVg==&user_id=cc+9nc3pVg==
```

when I tried with the following sample code for parsing the URL

```
//input code
const url = require("url");
 let uri = 'viberpa://aafff+a@viber.com?phone_number=vv+9nc3pVg==&user_id=cc+9nc3pVg==&token_created_time=2018-05-28T11:31:42.760Z'
 let uri_pasrse = url.parse(uri, true);
 console.log(uri_pasrse.query);
```

getting query strings:

```
{ phone_number: 'vv 9nc3pVg==',
  user_id: 'cc 9nc3pVg==',
  token_created_time: '2018-05-28T11:31:42.760Z' }
```

the query strings are excluded the + symbol. How can I get the original query strings using parsing method or suggest any alternative method?

Comment: Parsing implies decoding as well. Perhaps you just to split the fragments?

Comment: `+` is an encoding for a *space character*, if a `+` symbol is intended it should be encoded to %2b.  If you cannot do that consider pre-replacing `+` with another sequence, parsing then replacing back.

Comment: `+` is a special character in URIs and it needs to be URL-encoded (as `%2B`).

Answer (score 1):

Each query parameter must be encoded previously. In javascript (NodeJS in this case) you can use encodeURIComponent:

```
'use strict';

const url = require('url');
const uri = `viberpa://aafff+a@viber.com?phone_number=${encodeURIComponent('vv+9nc3pVg==')}&user_id=${encodeURIComponent('cc+9nc3pVg==')}&token_created_time=2018-05-28T11:31:42.760Z`;
const uri_parse = url.parse(uri, true);
console.log(uri_parse.query);
```

**Result:**

```
{ 
    phone_number: 'vv+9nc3pVg==',
    user_id: 'cc+9nc3pVg==',
    token_created_time: '2018-05-28T11:31:42.760Z'
}
```

Comment: Wouldn't it be more apt to use something like `encodeURIComponent` since it encodes the string properly instead of human-readable

Comment: Yes, I am applying encodeURIComponent for each query parameter. Other option in NodeJS is perform this task using querystring package (escape method)

Comment: I have tried with converting the query parameter to base64 encoding before parsing and so it works now. I think its works by either converting it to base64 or hex.
    let encodedUserId = Buffer.from(user_id).toString('base64');