# How can I get + sign from url parameter

Tags: node.js, typescript, express

I am trying to send a bloodGroup in a url parameter like A+ or A- but I can't get any sign.
https://blood-donation-servers.vercel.app/api/donor-list?bloodType=A+
how can I solve this?

I want to get + sign in response. When I sent a bloodtype like given api, in the console i get like A and a space.

Comment: Take a look at `encodeURIComponent()`.

Comment: Percent-encoding is where it's at. As @NickGris mentions, `encodeURIComponent` will change `A+` to `A%2B`.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [URL parsing issue : excluding '+' symbol](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50719437/url-parsing-issue-excluding-symbol)

Answer (score 0):

When certain characters that need to be sent in a URL would otherwise break/invalidate the URL, you have one of 2 options:

1. Pass the individual URL component into the encodeURIComponent function (as suggested by @NickGris)
   https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/encodeURIComponent
2. Pass the entire URL into the encodeURI function. This might be a better option if there are multiple parameters that might need encoding.
   https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/encodeURI

Be sure not to forget to decode the parameters on the BE by calling decodeURIComponent or decodeURI.